# Duplicate Items EWS C#

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I’m trying to find duplicate items in a public folder on the Exchange Server. But for some reason my routine isn’t finding any results.

```
foreach (Item item in folderL3.FindItems(new ItemView(1000)))
{
     item.Load();
     SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection searchFilterCollection = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And);
     searchFilterCollection.Add(new  SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.DateTimeCreated, item.DateTimeCreated));
     searchFilterCollection.Add(new  SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.DateTimeReceived, item.DateTimeReceived));
     searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.DateTimeSent, item.DateTimeSent));
     searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.Subject, item.Subject));
     searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.Size, item.Size));

     FindItemsResults<Item> results = exchange.FindItems(folderL3.Id, searchFilterCollection, new ItemView(1000));
     Console.WriteLine("Equal: " + results.Count());
     _countDoubleItems += results.Count(); 
}
```

It has no errors when I debug, and it iterates all items.
But the searchfilter isn't finding any items that are the same. And I know that there are duplicates, because I've put some in to test.

Comment: have you stepped thru the code..? are there any errors ..? can you please provide more information besides `my routine isn't finding any results` [MSDN Searching EWS in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn579421%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)

Comment: Assuming you have correctly configured your ExchangeService, have you ever gotten results?  I mean, have you reduced the number of SearchFilters and received any results?  Also you should try and step through as @MethodMan suggested.

Comment: Are you sure your duplicates have the exact same `DateTimeCreated` (etc.) values?

Comment: This exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: I left out the DateTimeCreated, and then in debug I see the same results.
But it doesn't get added to the results list.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out DateTime is not good material for comparing. So when I left those out, my result list worked just fine.
Thx for the help.